# How to rename/transform nested fields in json object using ElasticsearchSinkConnector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I'm using ElasticsearchSinkConnector to store data from Kafka topics to Elasticsearch indices. This is an example of a Kafka message:

```
{"ID" : "7d6203f4-3ae7-4daa-af03-71f98d619f7e",
 "Timestamp" : "2020-11-02T12:05:57.87639003Z",
 "Type" : "CREATION",
 "PlaceType" : "home",
 "Location" : {
        "Lat" : 43.7575119,
        "Lon" : 11.2921363
      },
"Created" : "2020-11-02T12:05:57.876390266Z",
"LastUpdated" : "2020-11-02T12:05:57.876390398Z"}
```

I would like to represent the `Location` object as **geo_point** in ES but **Lat/Lon** must be lowercase to be geo_point objects. I am using `ReplaceField$Value` to rename Location to "location" but I cannot rename the nested field, Lat/Lon. This is my snippet for renaming Location, Lat and Lon:

```
transforms: 'RenameField'
transforms.RenameField.type: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value
transforms.RenameField.renames: 'Location:location,location.Lat:lat,location.Lon:lon'
```

Location works, but Lat/Lon doesn't. In brief, I'd like to have the following result in ES:

```
{"ID" : "7d6203f4-3ae7-4daa-af03-71f98d619f7e",
 "Timestamp" : "2020-11-02T12:05:57.87639003Z",
 "Type" : "CREATION",
 "PlaceType" : "home",
 "location" : {
        "lat" : 43.7575119,
        "lon" : 11.2921363
      },
"Created" : "2020-11-02T12:05:57.876390266Z",
"LastUpdated" : "2020-11-02T12:05:57.876390398Z"}
```

**UPDATE**

Awesome, thank you very much. There was a problem creating my target stream in ksql-cli.

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM ES_PLACES_EVENT WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='es-places-event') AS
>    SELECT *,
>        STRUCT('lat' = LOCATION->LAT, 'lon'= LOCATION->LON) AS "location"
>    FROM PLACES_EVENT;
Can't find any functions with the name 'STRUCT'
```

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM ES_PLACES_EVENT WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='es-places-event') AS
>    SELECT *,
>        STRUCT('lat' = LOCATION->LAT, 'lon'= LOCATION->LON) AS 'location'
>    FROM PLACES_EVENT;
line 3:64: mismatched input ''location'' expecting {'NO', 'INTEGER', 'DATE', 'TIME', 'TIMESTAMP', 'INTERVAL', 'YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'HOUR', 'MINUTE', 'SECOND', 'ZONE', 'PARTITION', 'STRUCT', 'REPLACE', 'EXPLAIN', 'ANALYZE', 'FORMAT', 'TYPE', 'TEXT', 'SHOW', 'TABLES', 'SCHEMAS', 'COLUMNS', 'COLUMN', 'PARTITIONS', 'FUNCTIONS', 'FUNCTION', 'ARRAY', 'MAP', 'SET', 'RESET', 'SESSION', 'DATA', 'IF', IDENTIFIER, DIGIT_IDENTIFIER, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}
Caused by: org.antlr.v4.runtime.InputMismatchException
```

I tried to set the STRUCT name without quotes but ksql throws me an error like the first one.

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM ES_PLACES_EVENT WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='es-places-event') AS
>    SELECT *,
>        STRUCT('lat' = LOCATION->LAT, 'lon'= LOCATION->LON) AS GeoPointLocation
>    FROM PLACES_EVENT;
Can't find any functions with the name 'STRUCT'
```

Can you help me?

Comment: what version of ksqlDB are you using?

Comment: `Version: 5.1.2`

Comment: Ah - you need to >=  ksqlDB 0.7 (which shipped >= Confluent Platform 5.5)

Comment: Or use the other option that I showed to create a lat/long string pair `CAST(LOCATION->LAT AS VARCHAR)  + ',' + CAST(LOCATION->LON AS VARCHAR) AS "location_example_02"`

Comment: Indeed I used this one and everything works fine. Thank u again, you saved me!

Comment: Another question: if I have an ARRAY of STRUCT with the same fields, how can I get the same thing? `CAST (EXPLODE (OTHERPLACES) -> LOCATION-> LAT AS VARCHAR) + ',' + CAST (EXPLODE (OTHERPLACES) -> LOCATION-> LON AS VARCHAR) AS" geopoint_location_03 ""` doesn't work. Ksql throws me an error: `Caused by: Can't find any functions with the name 'EXPLODE'` Maybe it is related to the ksql version.

Comment: Another question -> another StackOverflow post please :) Makes it easier to answer, and for others to benefit from in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hit this exact same problem - and I'm not aware of an existing Single Message Transform that can help. You have a couple of options:

1. Write your own Single Message Transform to do this
2. Use ksqlDB to wrangle the schema, which is [the route I chose](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/telegram-bot-carparks/telegram_bot_demo.adoc#transform-the-data)

   ```
    CREATE STREAM OUTPUT_STREAM AS
        SELECT *,
        STRUCT("lat" := LATITUDE, "lon":= LONGITUDE) AS "location"
      FROM SOURCE_STREAM
      EMIT CHANGES;
   ```

You will also want to [create a mapping template](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/telegram-bot-carparks/docker-compose.yml#L133-L147) to prepare the Elasticsearch index if you haven't already

---

To expand on the ksqlDB example:

1. Populate source topic with the sample data:

   ```
   kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -P -t input_topic <<EOF
   { "ID": "7d6203f4-3ae7-4daa-af03-71f98d619f7e", "Timestamp": "2020-11-02T12:05:57.87639003Z", "Type": "CREATION", "PlaceType": "home", "Location": { "Lat": 43.7575119, "Lon": 11.2921363 }, "Created": "2020-11-02T12:05:57.876390266Z", "LastUpdated": "2020-11-02T12:05:57.876390398Z" }
   EOF
   ```
2. Taking a source topic of `source`, declare the ksqlDB `STREAM` object (which is basically Kafka topic with a schema overlaid):

   ```sql
   CREATE STREAM SOURCE_STREAM (ID VARCHAR,
                               Timestamp VARCHAR,
                               Type VARCHAR,
                               PlaceType VARCHAR,
                               Location STRUCT<Lat DOUBLE, Lon DOUBLE>,
                               Created VARCHAR,
                               LastUpdated VARCHAR)
           WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='input_topic', 
               VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
   ```
3. Confirm that the stream's schema is valid by selecting fields from the first message:

   ```sql
   ksql> SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';
   >
   Successfully changed local property 'auto.offset.reset' to 'earliest'. Use the UNSET command to revert your change.

   ksql> SELECT ID, PLACETYPE, LOCATION->LAT, LOCATION->LON FROM SOURCE_STREAM EMIT CHANGES LIMIT 1;
   +---------------------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
   |ID                                     |PLACETYPE |LAT        |LON        |
   +---------------------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
   |7d6203f4-3ae7-4daa-af03-71f98d619f7e   |home      |43.7575119 |11.2921363 |
   Limit Reached
   Query terminated
   ```
4. Create a target stream, mapping the lat/lon fields to lower-case names. Here I'm also showing the alternative approach of concatenating them, which Elasticsearch will also accept:

   ```sql
   CREATE STREAM TARGET_STREAM WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='target_topic') AS
       SELECT *, 
           STRUCT("lat" := LOCATION->LAT, "lon":= LOCATION->LON) AS "location_example_01",
           CAST(LOCATION->LAT AS VARCHAR)  + ',' + CAST(LOCATION->LON AS VARCHAR) AS "location_example_02"
       FROM SOURCE_STREAM;
   ```
5. Create an index template for Elasticsearch if the index does not already have the `geo_point` mapping declared. Here it'll match any index created that begins with `target`

   ```json
   curl --silent --show-error -XPUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
       http://localhost:9200/_index_template/rmoff_template01/ \
       -d'{
           "index_patterns": [ "target*" ],
           "template": {
               "mappings": {
                   "properties": {
                       "location_example_01": {
                           "type": "geo_point"
                       },
                       "location_example_02": {
                           "type": "geo_point"
                       }
                   }
               }
           } }'
   ```
6. Stream the data from Kafka to Elasticsearch using Kafka Connect. You can do configure this using the native Kafka Connect REST API, or do it directly from ksqlDB itself:

   ```sql
   CREATE SINK CONNECTOR SINK_ELASTIC_01 WITH (
   'connector.class'                     = 'io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector',
   'topics'                              = 'target_topic',
   'key.converter'                       = 'org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter',
   'value.converter'                     = 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter',
   'value.converter.schemas.enable'      = 'false',
   'connection.url'                      = 'http://elasticsearch:9200',
   'type.name'                           = '_doc',
   'key.ignore'                          = 'true',
   'schema.ignore'                       = 'true');
   ```
7. Inspect the mappings in the new Elasticsearch index

   ```json
   curl -XGET --silent --show-error http://localhost:9200"/target_topic/_mappings"  | jq '.'
   {
   "target_topic": {
       "mappings": {
       "properties": {
           "CREATED": {
           "type": "date"
           },
           "ID": {
           "type": "text",
           "fields": {
               "keyword": {
               "type": "keyword",
               "ignore_above": 256
               }
           }
           },
           "LASTUPDATED": {
           "type": "date"
           },
           "LOCATION": {
           "properties": {
               "LAT": {
               "type": "float"
               },
               "LON": {
               "type": "float"
               }
           }
           },
           "PLACETYPE": {
           "type": "text",
           "fields": {
               "keyword": {
               "type": "keyword",
               "ignore_above": 256
               }
           }
           },
           "TIMESTAMP": {
           "type": "date"
           },
           "TYPE": {
           "type": "text",
           "fields": {
               "keyword": {
               "type": "keyword",
               "ignore_above": 256
               }
           }
           },
           "location_example_01": {
           "type": "geo_point"
           },
           "location_example_02": {
           "type": "geo_point"
           }
       }
       }
   }
   }
   ```
8. View the data

   [image]

   [image]

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you. I updated my post, for a comment it was too many characters, after trying your solution. Thanks in advance.